# Get Before-Content of CSS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following CSS

```css
h1:before {
    content: "Chapter " counter(lvl1) "\000d\000a";
    counter-increment: lvl1;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
h1 {
    page-break-before: right;
}
```

and this HTML

```html
<p>...</p>
<h1>A Title</h1>
<p>...</p>
```

With the given CSS I get something like

```
Chapter 1
A Title
```

When I try to get the text with jQuery I get "A Title". Is there a possibility to get "Chapter 1\nA Title"?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `getComputedStyle()`:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this,':before').content);
});
```

`before()` is a jQuery method used to traverse the DOM, it gets/sets the preceding element, it does *not* access the pseudo-element.

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdMcv/2/), supplied by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913227/get-before-content-of-css-with-jquery#comment20921247_14913306).

Though there is the unfortunate caveat that this approach returns the *literal* string used in the `content` declaration, rather than the *actual* generated-content.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite right as it gets the literal `:before` content from the CSS file, not the actual generated content. The OP wants `Chapter 1`, not `Chapter " counter(lvl1)`... Cool answer but I don't think it would be useful in this case.

Comment: As @WesleyMurch said, this gives me `Chapter " Counter(lvl1)` instead of `Chapter 1`.

Comment: @MichaelS: indeed, and I'm trying to work around that. Unfortunately I'm having trouble doing so, so this may not be possible.

Comment: Any (easy) option to get this content for IE8? getComputedStyle with pseudo-elements is only supported by IE11+
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @retrovertigo: not that I'm aware of, no, unfortunately.