# Getting text of an element whose content was set at runtime by css media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I've an html `span` element as follows:

```
<span id="display-name" data-name="test123" data-sname="test"></span>
```

whose content is being set by css `media query` based on the device width.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  #display-name:after {
    content: attr(data-name)
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  #display-name:after {
    content: attr(data-sname)
  }
}
```

Later on I want to read the text using javascript as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var name = $("#display-name").text();
  alert(name);
});
```

But it appears that the value is not being set by the css. Any help ?

Full example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgpxwX

**Update**

The solution posted here : [Get Before-Content of CSS with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913227/get-before-content-of-css-with-jquery)

is giving a value `attr(data-name)`, but not the value `test123` which I need.

Modified codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgpxwX

Comment: Maybe because `:after` is not in DOM?

Comment: Not maybe, that's exactly what it is...

Comment: Ideally this is not a nice approach. But if you want to continue with pseudo classes then you can try like this.  getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('display-name'),"::after").getPropertyValue("content")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Before-Content of CSS with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913227/get-before-content-of-css-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to get element that is visible.

```
<span id="display-name">
    <span class="name">test123</span>
    <span class="sname">test</span>
</span>
```

whose content is being set by css media query based on the device width.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  #display-name .name {
    display: inline;
  }
  #display-name .sname {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  #display-name .name {
    display: none;
  }
  #display-name .sname {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

And jQuery

```
$('#display-name span:visible').text()
```

Comment: This works but with 1 glitch, the text `test123` is visible in the html (even with `width` and `height` set to `0px`). I don't want the text visible in the document.

Answer (score 0):

When text is set using the `content:;` property in CSS it's possible to retrieve this using JavaScript by first selecting the pseudo-element with something like:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#display-name'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content')
```

To break this down for you a little more, we're going to find our element:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#display-name')
```

Next we need to select its `:before` pseudo-element

```
var pseudo = window.getComputedStyle(el, ':before')
```

Now that we have the pseudo-element selected we can find the value of its `content` property:

```
var text = pseudo.getPropertyValue('content')
```

Here's a demo including sample HTML, CSS, and the JavaScript that will log the same name appearing in our HTML (via the responsive @media queries) in the browser's JavaScript console as well. When the browser goes so narrow CSS changes what's displayed, what is displayed in the console will update as well. In order to ensure that this code runs as the browser is resized note that I added an event listener to run this function on the window `resize` event!

```
<div id=display-name name=Jefferson sname=Jeff></div>

<style>
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    #display-name:before {
      content: attr(sname);
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 500px) {
    #display-name:before {
      content: attr(name);
    }
  }
</style>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',log)
  window.addEventListener('resize',log)

  function log(){
    var el = document.querySelector('#display-name')
    var pseudo = window.getComputedStyle(el, ':before')
    var text = pseudo.getPropertyValue('content')

    console.log(text)
  }
</script>
```

Hope this helps! For more information about getting and setting pseudo-elements from JavaScript, check out this article from David Walsh: https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

Comment: Same problem as I mentioned in my **update**, it is printing values `attr(name)` and `attr(sname)` instead of `Jefferson` and `Jeff` respectively.

Comment: When I view the codepen I see the `test123` in the alert, have you tried this in any other browsers? You should be seeing `Jefferson` and `Jeff`, not `attr(name)` or `attr(sname)`.

Answer (score -1):

The `:after` pseudo isn't adding the content into the DOM element, so calling `.text()` will return nothing.
 You should read more about the `css pseudos`.